# Change button text alpha without changing background

Tags: java, android, xml

I have read loads of threads about changing the button's alpha in Android Studio without affecting the text, but I want to know if there is any possibility of doing the opposite. I would like to animate a transition where, once clicked, the text in the button slowly fades out.
I know this can be done using a TextView and a background, but I want to know if there is a way for buttons, because I don't want to lose its style and that can't be applied to TextViews.
Thank you!